angular-auth-oidc-client calls common endpoint in Azure AD despite mentioning authority

Above is the config defined to authenticate with Azure AD, but when the application is loaded, it calls common endpoint url of Azure although I have defined authority above. Found while debugging that it takes url from authWellKnownEndpoints which it generates by default.
Should I override that and how? Or pass some parameters to give priority to authority - otherwise what is the use of it?
Workaround of this problem is to supply authWellKnownEndpoints in the config but ideally library should itself call correct endpoints as in future endpoints might get changed by Azure. Therefore still looking for help on this.

Resolved above by posting authWellKnownEndPointUrls with the same url as authority. Actually it doesn't matter what authority contains but what matters is what authWellKnownEndPointUrls contains although docs say they use authority only.
